# How do I know what format the token is in that gets sent from ADFS to my web app?

Tags: c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4, token, saml-2.0, adfs2.0

Here's the scenario: my web app's authentication is outsourced to ADFS (Active Directory Federation Services).  ADFS provides a log-in for the user.  Once the user logs in and is authenticated, the user is redirected back to my app, and ADFS sends a token to my app.  How do I find out what format that token is in?  By format, I mean SAML, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is in the FederationMetadata.xml file.  Look for the part where it says

> fed:TokenTypesOffered